# How to multiplicate 2 numbers in one string with 3rd outside the string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to calculate strings with formula which is outside of the string , some times i get strings with two numbers separated by space and my formula just calculate the first number from the string.

```php
$string = "225cm x 70cm";

$outputString = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/ ', ' ', $string);// output here is string(12) "225 70 "  

$inches = intval($outputString) * 0.39370; 
$inches_pre = round($inches  / 0.5) * 0.5; // output here is just 85 instead of string "85.5 27.5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
$string = "225cm x 70cm";
if (preg_match_all('/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $string, $m)) {
    $inches = implode(" ", array_map(function ($x) { return round(intval($x) * 0.39370  / 0.5) * 0.5; }, $m[0]));
    echo $inches;
}
// => 85.5 27.5
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/5jUol).

With `preg_match_all('/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $string, $m)`, you extract all numbers into `$m[0]`, and then you process each inside an `array_map` and then join the results into a single string with `implode`.

Comment: how can make them back in the sentence , like my strings is $string = "This is 225cm x70 cm garment" how can become to This is 85.5'' x 27.5'' garment ?

Comment: @Bulgarian_power `echo preg_replace_callback('/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', function($m) { return round(intval($m[0]) * 0.39370  / 0.5) * 0.5 . '"'; }, $string);`, see [the PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ikV2L).

Comment: Wow nice ! Thank you so much !